# Calendar.getWeeksInWeekYear return diffrent values for same year but in diffrent system

Tags: java

I am using this method to get the number of weak in a year but in my computer for the year 2020 it returns 53 but in the server it returns 52 !! 
I have no idea why?

```
Integer getNumberOfWeeksInYear(@PathParam("year") int year) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);

        return calendar.getWeeksInWeekYear();
    }
```

Comment: That method won't currently compile. Please could you post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: First, don't use `Calendar`, it's an old and outdated class, and it was always poorly designed. Look into java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Second, different locales have different ways if delimiting and numbering the weeks, so both results are probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers — 52 weeks and 53 weeks — are correct. In different locales, that is.

Year 2020, a leap year, begins on a Wednesday and ends on a Thursday. Different locales count weeks in different ways. For example:

- In Tunisia (ar-TN locale) weeks begin on Saturday and the first week in a year is the week that contains January 1. So week 1 is from Saturday 28 December 2019 through Friday January 4, 2020. Week 52 is from 21 through 27 December. The week beginning 28 December is considered week 1 of 2021. So there are 52 weeks in the week year 2020.
- In the ISO calendar system, the international standard, weeks begin on Monday and week 1 is the first week that contains at least 4 days of the new year. So week 1 is from Monday 30 December 2019 through Sunday January 5. Week 53 is from 28 December through Sunday 3 January 2021. So there are 53 weeks.

A couple of more points to note:

- The `Calendar` class that you were using is poorly designed and long outdated.
- Your code will work incorrectly in a couple of corner cases.

  - `Calendar.getInstance` gives you an instance of concrete subclass of `Calendar` based on default locale. It is not guaranteed to give you a `Calendar` that supports `getWeeksInWeekYear()` at all, so your code may crash.
  - If you run your code on a day near New Year belonging to a week of the previous or the next year, you will get the week count of that previous or next year, not the year you queried.

A correct and modern way to get the count of weeks of a week year is:

```
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-TN"));
    int weekYear = 2020;
    // The number of weeks is the same as the week number of the last week in the week year.
    // So find a date in that last week and query its week number.
    // The way to find a date in the last week is:
    // find a date in week 1 of the following year and subtract 1 week.
    LocalDate aDateInWeek1OfTheFollowingYear = LocalDate.of(weekYear + 1, Month.FEBRUARY, 1)
            .with(wf.weekOfYear(), 1);
    LocalDate aDateInLastWeek = aDateInWeek1OfTheFollowingYear.minusWeeks(1);
    int lastWeekNumber = aDateInLastWeek.get(wf.weekOfYear());

    System.out.format("Week year %d has %d weeks.%n", weekYear, lastWeekNumber);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Week year 2020 has 52 weeks.